# Create recursive query where column values need to get based on another column | ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables where one table has list of issues and another table has its parent issue in form of issue id.

I am only mentioning required columns

1st table

ID, ISSUENUM, PROJECTKEY

---

2nd Table

JSON_VALUE has parent_id which is ID from 1st table

---

END result expectation

ID, ISSUENUM, PROJECT KEY, PARENT_ISSUENUM, PARENT_PROJECT_KEY

I have query till this point, but unable to make hierarchical/ recursive query

```
(select json_value(EP.JSON_VALUE, '$.parent_id' RETURNING NUMBER)as xyz
from JIR.ENTITY_PROPERTY EP where EP.ENTITY_ID = JI.ID AND EP.ENTITY_NAME = 'IssueProperty' 
AND json_exists(EP.JSON_VALUE, '$.parent_id'))as parent_id
from jir.project p,jir.jiraissue JI
where p.id = ji.project
and (p.pkey = 'ABCDEF' OR p.pkey = 'UVWXYZ')
```

How to use this ID which I have as column `parent_id` and use it to get `parent_issue_num` and `parent_project_key`

Comment: Sounds like you need to make use of `CONNECT BY`: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text. Also, which version of Oracle are you running?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. I improved the query on getting parent_id and get parent_key using column query itself

```
select  JI.ID, 
(select P.PKEY||'-'||ji2.issuenum
from JIR.ENTITY_PROPERTY EP 
inner join jir.jiraissue JI2 on ji2.id=json_value(EP.JSON_VALUE, '$.parent_id' RETURNING NUMBER)
inner join jir.project p2 on p2.id=ji2.project
where EP.ENTITY_ID = JI.ID AND EP.ENTITY_NAME = 'IssueProperty' 
AND json_exists(EP.JSON_VALUE, '$.parent_id'))as parent_id
from jir.project p,jir.jiraissue JI
where p.id = ji.project
and (p.pkey = 'ABCDEF' OR p.pkey = 'UVWXYZ')
```

This small change resolved the issue

```
inner join jir.jiraissue JI2 on ji2.id=json_value(EP.JSON_VALUE, '$.parent_id' RETURNING NUMBER)
inner join jir.project p2 on p2.id=ji2.project
```